The WebView is not displaying on the screen with the current code
What could be wrong with my code? <Text>Awesome </Text> is visible on the screen, but the WebView is not showing.
import React, { useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import BottomSheet, { BottomSheetView } from "@gorhom/bottom-sheet";
import WebView from "react-native-webview";

const App = () => {
  // ref
  const bottomSheetRef = useRef<BottomSheet>(null);

  // callbacks
  const handleSheetChanges = useCallback((index: number) => {
    console.log("handleSheetChanges", index);
  }, []);

  // renders
  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={styles.container}>
      <BottomSheet ref={bottomSheetRef} onChange={handleSheetChanges}>
        <BottomSheetView style={styles.contentContainer}>
          <Text>Awesome </Text>
          <WebView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            source={{
              uri: "https://gorhom.dev/react-native-bottom-sheet/usage",
            }}
          />
        </BottomSheetView>
      </BottomSheet>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "grey",
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 36,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default App;

enter image description here
I’ve looked through the official documentation and various articles, but I couldn’t find a suitable solution.

Tre setting flex: 1 on BottomSheet as well.

Wrap your WebView in a View.
